# Custom 404 does not work on any dir/file greating than the 1st level ? advice plz

Tags: http-status-code-404

I need to cover all nonexistent directories or nonexistent files within the whole of my website gb-online.co.uk

I have 404.shtml 404style.css and gears.png in the domain root directory.

It only gives the correct 404 with the 1st level nonexistent directories or nonexistent files
ie
https://gb-online.co.uk/1.php
or
https://gb-online.co.uk/1

anything above this 1st level does not pickup the css file and thus does not work, but it picks up the 404.shtml
ie
https://gb-online.co.uk/1/2.php
or
https://gb-online.co.uk/1/2

Surely it cannot be that I have to apply it to every directory. I must be doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Got that bit working by adding ../ to the path of the css file in the shtml file.

However when 'inside' prestashop any 404 does not work, it only brings up the default prestashop 404

ie
https://gb-online.co.uk/neweshop/1

Any ideas